# How do I plot a line graph after concatenating and dropping columns

Tags: dataframe, matplotlib, axis

I had raw data of TimeStamp and PV output for different setups.

I have csv files like the above for >365 days. Timestamp = time of the day for each datapoint. pv_conc are values for one output from different setups, and just means the power output for that setup. I wanted to find average output across the days at the specific TimeStamps to plot a graph of power against time graph. I concatenated, merged, and dropped columns that I had typo errors in the labelling.

But I can't seem to plot pv_conc against TimeStamp.
I've tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
excel_dir = '/kaggle/input/pv-output-1/PV 2122'

first_file = '/kaggle/input/pv-output-1/PV 2122/1 Apr 2021.csv'
PV_2122 = pd.read_csv(first_file)

for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('/kaggle/input/pv-output-1'):
for filename in filenames:
    name = str(os.path.join(excel_dir, filename))  # Corrected from 
first_file to filename
    if name.endswith('.csv'):
       file_path = pd.read_csv(name)
       PV_2122 = pd.concat([file_path, PV_2122], ignore_index=True)

PV_2122['pv_conc'] = PV_2122['PV Conc '].combine_first(PV_2122['PV Conc'])
PV_2122['pv_conc'] = PV_2122['PV 
Conc'].combine_first(PV_2122['pv_conc'])

drop_conc = ['PV Conc ', 'PV Conc']
PV_2122.drop(drop_conc, axis =1, inplace = True)
PV_2122.head()  

average_pv_conc = PV_2122.groupby(['TimeStamp'])['pv_conc'].mean()
```

PROBLEM STARTS HERE

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6)) 
plt.plot(df['TimeStamp'], df['pv_conc'], label='PV Output', marker='o', linestyle='-', color='b')

plt.xlabel('TimeStamp')
plt.ylabel('pv_conc')
plt.title('PV Output Over Time')

plt.show()
```

But the error for this cell is:
KeyError: 'TimeStamp'

Comment: Please don't use images of code/data. Provide a fully reproducible [mre].

Comment: hey @mozway the images of code/data are actually not the issue. The issue is the one at the bottom, which is typed out. I was providing the images more for background understanding of whats my data that I've loaded in and how it looks like!

Comment: Yes it's an issue, we cannot reproduce your problem. Please read [ask].

Comment: @mozway let me know if this is better

Comment: Is `df` in the second code blocks equal to `average_pv_conc` ?

Comment: i dont know actually... really new to this. The only file I've uploaded is PV_2122 and that's it. The rest are amendments to the data in PV_2122. TimeStamp and pv_conc are the columns in PV_2122

Comment: `KeyError: 'TimeStamp'` means your dataframe doesn't have a column with the exact name `TimeStamp'`. You need to take a look at `df.columns` to know the exact names (including possible spaces or different uppercase/lowercase). If `'TimeStamp'` is the index of the dataframe, you can try `plt.plot(df.index, df['pv_conc', ...]`

Comment: Please provide data for minimum reproducable example

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys my friend managed to solve this for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  "TimeStamp": TimeStamp,
  "average_pv_green": average_pv_green.values
```

})

```
df['SortingTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp'], format='%H:%M')
sorted_indices = df['SortingTime'].argsort()
df = df.loc[sorted_indices].reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.drop(columns='SortingTime')
```

marker_size = 0.5

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 4))

plt.scatter(df['TimeStamp'], df['average_pv_green'], label='PV Output',         marker='.', color='b', s=marker_size)

plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Energy Generated/kWh')
plt.title('PV green')
tick_positions = range(len(df['TimeStamp']))
tick_labels = df['TimeStamp']

plt.xticks(tick_positions, tick_labels, rotation=90, ha='right')
for i, label in enumerate(plt.gca().xaxis.get_ticklabels()):
    if i % 3 != 0:
        label.set_visible(False)
    
plt.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=5) 

plt.legend()  

plt.show()
```